# How to transfer call using transfer application with H323

Tags: asterisk

I am using the asterisks. I want to transfer call using transfer application with h323 protocols.  But I am not able to transfer call.

In the extensions.conf file I  have added the following content.

```
exten => 118,1,answer()
exten => 118,n,set(__TRANSFER_CONTEXT=transfer)
exten => 118,n,saynumber(567)
exten => 118,n,wait(1)
exten => 118,n,transfer(H323/119)
exten => 119,1,answer()
exten => 119,n,saynumber(222)
exten => 119,n,hangup()
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a similar issue, sometimes transfer will not be possible if there is a mismatch with channel technology.

If one wants to use Transfer application

```
Transfer([Tech/]dest[|options]):
```

You must ensure that if TECH (SIP, IAX2, LOCAL etc) is used, only
an incoming call with the same channel technology will be transferred. If the incoming channel is SIP but you want to transfer to IAX it won't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved with Goto command. Transfer is used to transfer calls to real devices/users but if you want to stick with that you can try:

exten => 118,n,transfer(Local/119@your_context)

or simply

exten => 118,n,transfer(Local/119)